# Is there any relationship between Appium's driver.reset() and the "noReset" or "fullReset" capabilities?

Tags: appium

Does the use of Appium's `driver.reset()` method require the capabilities `noReset` or `fullReset` to be set to any particular values?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `driver.reset()`, appium considers it as hard reset and it does not deal with any values of `noReset` or `fullReset`.

If you don't use `driver.reset()`, appium considers the `noReset` value as `false` by default.